# Reverse comment pagination numbers

Tags: comments, pagination, paginate-comments-links

I would like to reverse the comment pagination numbers so that the newest comments show on page 1 instead of the last page. I did an array_reverse for the comments_array and set the Wordpress Discussion Settings to first page displayed by default - everything works fine except when someone leaves a comment it doesn't take in consideration the array_reverse and it takes the user to the link where the comment would be without the array reverse and obviously the comment is not there.

I noticed that the redirect comes from wp-comments-post.php

`$location = empty($_POST['redirect_to']) ? get_comment_link($comment_id) : $_POST['redirect_to'] . '#comment-' . $comment_id;`

Is there a way to get the correct redirect link after a comment is submitted? Or is there a simpler way to get the comment pagination numbers reversed? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i've used

```
wp_list_comments
```

like this:

```
<?php if (class_exists('Walker_Comment_Wink'))
    $walker = new Walker_Comment_Wink();
  else
    $walker = '';

 wp_list_comments(array('walker' => $walker, 'type' => 'comment' , 'callback' => 'theme_comment2')); ?>
```

i used the plugin http://winkpress.com/articles/fix-reversed-comments-pagination/ to fix the "* and 1 comment" weirdness.

You have the option to pass

> **$reverse_top_level** (boolean) (optional) 
>   Setting this to true will display the most recent comment first then going back in order.
>   Default: null

you can check it in action here http://www.joaoleitao.com/viagens/acerca-do-autor/

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it achievable withing the admin discussion setting page?

> Break comments into pages with N top level comments per page and the
>   First/Last page displayed by default. Comments should be displayed
>   with the older/newer comments on the top of each page.

Comment: Yes, but you don't get the newest comments on page 1 - you get them on the last page. And as I mentioned I did a array reverse and that makes them appear on page 1, but then the problem becomes when someone submits a comment they get redirected to the wrong comment page.

Comment: Oh, I never select that option. I thought that it will behave as I expected. But maybe you give a try on get_comments(), instead of using array_reverse, you can give the arguments for get_comments() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments